# Seleccionar fila en GridView - DevExpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

Buen día,

Como puedo hacer exactamente esto para seleccionar, pero con el gridview o gridcontrol de DevExpress?

```
            cbo_condicion.Text = this.dgv_list_maestro.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            txt_cod_contacto.Text = this.dgv_list_maestro.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txt_cod_cliente.Text = this.dgv_list_maestro.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            cbo_tipo_contacto.Text = this.dgv_list_maestro.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que estás usando XtraGrid de DevExpress.
Utiliza el método GetRowCellValue(fila,nombreDeColumna) del GridView

```
dgv_list_maestro.GetRowCellValue(0, colXXXX);
```

nombreDeColumna es el nombre que puedes ver en el diseñador del gridView
También puedes usar la sobrecarga que utiliza el nombre del campo del origen de datos al que has enlazado la fila. No puedes utilizar el nº de columna.

```
txt_cod_contacto.Text = dgv_list_maestro.GetRowCellValue(0, "cod_contacto");
```